# Iterating a for loop over groups in a dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by

I am trying to apply a for loop to a dataset. The loop is supposed to generate a sequence for a certain (unequal) number of rows and then start over. I can group these rows. I have managed to write a loop, that works for the first of my groups, but then stops (also throws a bunch of warnings, "numerical expression has 226 elements: only the first used"). I get that it is only iterating over the first group, but then the values that make up the new variable im creating with this loop change and it crashes. Can anyone help me?
I am terrible at recreating dataset, im sorry!

```
start <- c(1901, 1902, 1950, 1980, 1980)
end <- c(1905, 1910, 1951, 1999, 1985)
year <- NA
group <- c("apples","apples","apples", "Banana","cherry")
df <- data.frame(start, end, year, group)
df$count <- df$end - df$start
df<- df[rep(rownames(df), df$count +1), ]
```

This is my loop:

```
for(i in row_along(df)){
df$year[[i]] <- rep(df$start:df$end)[i]
}
```

I want each row to have a "year" value, between start and end (for each year one row with the same values, except for year). I have an unequal amount of rows (start and end dates), depending on two other variables. 
Grouping with dplyr is not a problem, I can manage to make a list of dataframes (with split) but thats about it. I'm stuck.

Just in case

```
row_along <- function(df) seq(nrow(df))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(start, end) %>%
  mutate(year = start[1]:end[1])
# # A tibble: 42 x 5
# # Groups:   start, end [5]
#    start   end  year group  count
#    <dbl> <dbl> <int> <fct>  <dbl>
#  1  1901  1905  1901 apples     4
#  2  1901  1905  1902 apples     4
#  3  1901  1905  1903 apples     4
#  4  1901  1905  1904 apples     4
#  5  1901  1905  1905 apples     4
#  6  1902  1910  1902 apples     8
#  7  1902  1910  1903 apples     8
#  8  1902  1910  1904 apples     8
#  9  1902  1910  1905 apples     8
# 10  1902  1910  1906 apples     8
# # ... with 32 more rows
```

In your attempt, you have `df$start:df$end`. `df$start` is a vector, the whole column of all the start values, and the same for `df$end`, which is why you are getting warnings: while `1901:1905` is well defined, `c(1901, 1901, 1901):c(1905, 1905, 1905)` is not, and the warning tells you that only the first element on each side is used. This is why I use `start[1]:end[1]` in the answer. *Within each group*, we only need to consider the first `start` and `end` values to generate the full `year` sequence. (Your attempt also had the issue that it didn't really do anything with the groups---`dplyr` makes grouping easy.)

Comment: Yep. Thank you so much!! Why try doing it the easy way if it can be done complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be loop through corresponding elements of 'start', 'end' with `map2` (from `purrr`), get the sequence in a `list` and then `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(year = map2(start, end, `:`)) %>% 
    unnest
```