# Holes in ordered groups

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a data frame ordered by `id` and `year`, observed n times over a number of years. Number of observations per individual per year is irregular. I define a "hole" in the data as an observation where `x2=1` and the observation immediatly above, for the same `id` (not necessarily for the same`year`), is equal to 0. For example, individual A has a hole in 2002. When this happens, I need to create a variable where I store the value of `x1` immediatly above, for which `x2=0`. In the example of individual A, I would then need the new variable to equal 5 when `x2=1`.

```
x1 = c(5,3,2,2,5,7,7,3,4,8)
x2 = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
id = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D")
year = c(2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2001,2001,2002,2001,2002)

df = data.frame(year,id,x1,x2)
```

Considering this sample data frame, I would need the new variable to look like this:

```
outcome = c(.,5,.,.,.,.,.,7,.,4)
```

The dataset I'm working with has close to 10.000.000 observations, for 3.000.000 individuals over 4 years, so I can't do this manually. Is there any generalized way to achieve this that works with any dataset, regardless of dimension?

I went through a few posts here using for loops to iterate over groups (one example was this one [Iterating a for loop over groups in a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678284/iterating-a-for-loop-over-groups-in-a-dataset)) but I wasn't able to apply any of it. I've been trying to do it in R after being unsuccessful in stata 14. I wasn't able to find any post that applied to ordered groups, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to get your `outcome` with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    outcome = ifelse(x2 == 1 & lag(x2) == 0, lag(x1), NA)
  )
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   id [4]
    year id       x1    x2 outcome
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  2001 A         5     0      NA
 2  2002 A         3     1       5
 3  2003 A         2     0      NA
 4  2001 B         2     1      NA
 5  2002 B         5     0      NA
 6  2001 C         7     1      NA
 7  2001 C         7     0      NA
 8  2002 C         3     1       7
 9  2001 D         4     0      NA
10  2002 D         8     1       4
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I was able to actually understand the syntax! Thank you very much. I'm also very glad to have learned about that ```lag()``` operator!